# How can I set the focus to a certain element in a form using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

My page has a form that has a text field in it. I'd like to set the focus to that text field as soon as the page loads, so that users do not have to click it to start typing. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `focus()` method on the object.

For example:

```
document.getElementById("something").focus();
...
<input type='text' id='something' />
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried that first, before posting, but it didn't appear to be working right. I must have not refreshed the page good enough. :P

Answer (score 2):

you have to select your element first and then focus it by using focus() :P

```
function hokusfocus(e)
{
  var fokus = document.getElementById(e);
  fokus.focus();
}

onload = hokusfocus("yourId"); /* makes sure your document is loaded before the focus */
```

Comment: I'm not such a fast typer. So i have to use my imagination to get points :P

Answer (score 1):

Did you try googling this?

`document.getElementById("textboxId").focus();`

Comment: I checked to make sure this question wasn't a duplicate. I'm fairly certain that that is the only prerequisite to asking a question. I feel that any question that hasn't been asked before is a decent contribution to this site as long as it isn't flat out stupid.

Comment: @Rayne: You're right. Pay no attention to those saying otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

use autofocus attribute like this:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<dl>
<dt><label>username:</label><dt>
<dd><input type="text" autofocus></dd>

<dt><label>password:</label><dt>
<dd><input type="password"></dd>

</dl>
</body>
```